# How to implement CSS button animations into your website?

Tags: css, animation

I stumbled across this website that lists CSS button animations. I have linked it --> https://buttonanimations.github.io/ I don't know if its just me but when I try to implement the animations into my website (Copy and paste) they just break. Is it on their end or mine, maybe they didn't input the animations correctly into the website.

(Currently using Safari) (I mean it should work right?)

Comment: Might want to include what your code currently looks like.  We can't help you find the problem if we can't see what you've tried to do.  Did you paste the CSS code they provided in a referenced .css file, or included inside <style> elements in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animations can be used by clicking on the animation on the page, copying the value:

```
.button_name:hover{ color: blue; -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); -ms-transform: scale(1.2); transform: scale(1.2); animation-duration: 1s; transition-duration: 1s; transition-property: 1s; }
.button_name { width: 300px; height: 45px; background-color: #cccccc; }
```

and putting the code in a stylesheet or `<style>` element.

Note that the `.button_name` selector should be replaced by the class(such as `hover_button`) that the element has when putting the code in a file or `style` element:

```
<button class="hover_button">Test</button>
```

```css
.hover_button:hover{ color: blue; -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); -ms-transform: scale(1.2); transform: scale(1.2); animation-duration: 1s; transition-duration: 1s; transition-property: 1s; }
.hover_button { width: 300px; height: 45px; background-color: #cccccc; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
.hover_button:hover{ color: blue; -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); -ms-transform: scale(1.2); transform: scale(1.2); animation-duration: 1s; transition-duration: 1s; transition-property: 1s; }
.hover_button { width: 300px; height: 45px; background-color: #cccccc; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button class="hover_button">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you could do that but for me personally, I think the easiest way to do this would be to use the animation attribute in the  section. Here is an example:

```css
#popoutbutton {
font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
border: 3px solid #666;
background-color: black;
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
transition: background-color 300ms ease-out 100ms;
}
#popoutbutton:hover {
background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<a 
target="popup"                          onclick="window.open('WEBSITEURLHERE','popup','width=400,height=600'); return false;">
  <button id="popoutbutton">Pop Out</button>
</a>
```

This, at least for me personally, is the easiest way to do this.